# Целесообразность использования EventBus

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, eventbus

Здравствуйте.

Заранее хочу сказать, что самой библиотекой EventBus еще не пользовался, но возник вопрос по поводу целесообразности ее использования.

**Что есть:**

`Activity` с `ViewPager`, встроенным в `TabLayout` с 2 фрагментами. На каждом фрагменте находится по `RecyclerView`. Информация для них берется из `ArrayList'ов`, которые обновляются по `ValueEventListener'у` `Google Firebase`.

**Как это выглядит сейчас:**

В начале объявляется `SectionsPagerAdapter`, который инициализирует 2 фрагмента. Все они находятся в одном классе. Внутри каждого фрагмента в методе `onCreateView` инициализируется `RecyclerView` и адаптер для него. Данные берутся из `private static ArrayList'ов`. Сами адаптеры тоже объявлены `private static`. Внутри же `ValueEventListener'а` обновляются эти `ArrayList'ы` и адаптеры соответственно. В ту же кучу навалены `private static searchView` и `FragmentManager`, т.к. они нужны для работы внутри фрагментов.

Как по мне, это все выглядит и работает ужасно. В связи с этим хочу узнать мнение по этому поводу:

- Стоит ли это переделать, используя EventBus (и возможно ли)
- Стоит ли это переделать, используя какие-либо стандартные методы (и какие)
- Оставить все как есть с учетом утечек памяти

Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Обрезанный код класса:

```
public class UserActionsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{
private static Context context;

private ViewPager viewPager;
private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

private static RecyclerView unverifiedUsersView;
private static RecyclerView usersView;

private static DatabaseReference databaseReference;
private ValueEventListener valueEventListener;

private static ArrayList<User> unverifiedUsersList = new ArrayList<User>();
private static ArrayList<User> usersList = new ArrayList<User>();
private static UnverifiedUserRecyclerAdapter adapter;
private static UserRecyclerAdapter adapter1;

private static FragmentManager fragmentManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_actions);

    context = UserActionsActivity.this;

    initializeComponents();
    setEvents();
}

private void initializeComponents(){
    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
    viewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}

private void setEvents() {
    valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (!search) {
                unverifiedUsersList = Globals.Downloads.getSpecificVerifiedUserList(dataSnapshot, DatabaseVariables.Users.DATABASE_UNVERIFIED_USER_TABLE);
                adapter = new UnverifiedUserRecyclerAdapter(getApplicationContext(), unverifiedUsersList);
                unverifiedUsersView.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                usersList = Globals.Downloads.getVerifiedUserList(dataSnapshot);
                adapter1 = new UserRecyclerAdapter(getApplicationContext(), usersList);
                usersView.setAdapter(adapter1);
                adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };
}


public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if (position == 0)
            return FirstFragment.newInstance();
        else
            return SecondFragment.newInstance();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "Не авторизованные";
            case 1:
                return "Все";
        }
        return null;
    }
}

public static class FirstFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recycler, container, false);

        unverifiedUsersView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recycler);
        LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);;

        adapter = new UnverifiedUserRecyclerAdapter(context, unverifiedUsersList);

        unverifiedUsersView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        unverifiedUsersView.setHasFixedSize(false);

        unverifiedUsersView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        return v;
    }

    public static FirstFragment newInstance() {
        FirstFragment f = new FirstFragment();
        return f;
    }
}

public static class SecondFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recycler, container, false);

        usersView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recycler);
        LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);;

        adapter1 = new UserRecyclerAdapter(context, usersList);

        usersView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        usersView.setHasFixedSize(false);

        usersView.setAdapter(adapter1);
        adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();

        return v;
    }

    public static SecondFragment newInstance() {
        SecondFragment f = new SecondFragment();
        return f;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обычно я не причисляю себя к глупым людям, но в данном вопросе я был полным дураком, пока г-н pavel163 не навел меня на нужную мысль. Опять же, не знаю, насколько это все правильно, но реализовал я все таким способом:

Вынес все фрагменты и `SectionsPagerAdapter` в отдельный класс. Выглядит это все так:

```
public class UserActionsFragments {
public static class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private FirstFragment firstFragment;
    private SecondFragment secondFragment;
    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if (position == 0)
            return FirstFragment.newInstance();
        else
            return SecondFragment.newInstance();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "Не авторизованные";
            case 1:
                return "Все";
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        Fragment createdFragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                firstFragment = (FirstFragment) createdFragment;
                break;
            case 1:
                secondFragment = (SecondFragment) createdFragment;
                break;
        }
        return createdFragment;
    }

    public void updateFirstFragment(%параметры%){
        firstFragment.updateContent(%параметры%);
    }

    public void updateSecondFragment(%параметры%){
        secondFragment.updateContent(%параметры%);
    }
}

public static class FirstFragment extends Fragment {
    RecyclerView unverifiedUsersView;
    boolean result;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recycler, container, false);

        unverifiedUsersView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recycler);

        return v;
    }

    public void updateContent(%параметры%) {
        LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        unverifiedUsersView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        unverifiedUsersView.setHasFixedSize(false);

        UnverifiedUserRecyclerAdapter adapter = new UnverifiedUserRecyclerAdapter(context, unverifiedUsersList);
        unverifiedUsersView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

        public static FirstFragment newInstance() {
        FirstFragment f = new FirstFragment();
        return f;
    }
}

//аналогично для 2 фрагмента
}
```

И в нужный мне момент (например при обновлении в `ValueEventListener`) обращаюсь к `mSectionsPagerAdapter`, например

```
mSectionsPagerAdapter.updateSecondFragment(usersList, UserActionsActivity.this);
```

Не знаю, насколько это правильно, но, в результате, в Activity не осталось ни одного `static` поля. Лично для меня - это победа. Ткните в меня палкой, если я опять сделал что-то страшное, пока я не могу принять свой ответ еще 22 часа.

Смущает лишь то, что приходится каждый раз устанавливать `LayoutManager`.

Answer (score 1):

Зачем у Вас так много static полей? Из-за этого скорее и течет. Тут EventBus не поможет. Да и на мой взгляд eventbus можно назвать антипатерном.

Comment: Ну, по сути, вопрос и заключается в том, как избавиться от этого безобразия.

Comment: Тогда прикрепите код

Comment: Добавил код. Понимаю, что это все очень криво сделано, но я не смог найти решения лучше.

Comment: А почему у Вас все поля static? Вы понимаете как это работает вообще? Вынесите все классы вложенные. Уберите статики. Создайте метод во фрагментах для добавления данных. данные во фрагмент через этот метод передавайте. Обновление когда будет приходит обновляйте список.

Comment: Получается, что я создаю фрагмент, при помощи метода получаю для него необходимые данные методом из активити, а потом возвращаю из него ссылку на RecyclerView для работы в основной активити?